# How to ensure apps use Nemo to browse?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus, nemo

On my Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Nemo and made it the default file manager using the following commands:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

My problem: **When an app needs to browse my files** ("Open Folder" from VSCode, "Other" from Startup Disk Creator, etc), **Nautilus is used**.

How can I ensure Nemo is used even in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: That's probably not exactly Nautilus, but rather the [GTK file chooser](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) dialog.

Comment: It is indeed gtk file chooser, and it looks like there isn't a way to use nemo for that (which would allow for the Bookmarked directories to be consistent)

Thanks!